# SQL query to find weekdays in continuous years

Tags: mysql, datetime, 2-digit-year

to everyone I am little bit of struggling with MySQL query i need to get list of Saturdays  list for the past 5 years and i am confused  so please help me!!

Comment: How does your table look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**WEEKDAY()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) function.

```
Returns the weekday index for date (0 = Monday, 1 = Tuesday, … 6 = Sunday).
```

This query will return all Saturday in your datetable  date column = [**MySQL datetime**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html)

```
SELECT * FROM `datetable` WHERE  WEEKDAY(`dates`) = 5
```